# how to Convert this query to linq of codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I don't understand how to convert this query into codeigniter linq

```
SELECT prdctSubCatId 
FROM productinfo 
WHERE prdctSubCatId = (
  SELECT prdctSubCatId 
  FROM productinfo 
  WHERE id='27'
```

)
Instead of id ='27' I want to pass id=$id, then how can I do this

Comment: I think @Nithin Krishnan P's answer is what you want. If your CI version is 3 you can do it alternative way using  `get_compiled_select`

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('prdctSubCatId')->from('productinfo');
$this->db->where('`prdctSubCatId`= (SELECT `prdctSubCatId` FROM `productinfo` WHERE id=27 )', NULL, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $this->db->select('prdctSubCatId');
    $this->db->where('id',27);
    return $this->db->get('productinfo')->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT prdctSubCatId FROM productinfo WHERE prdctSubCatId=27");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```